# How can I create multiple instances of an assosiated model from a rails 3 form_for when I don't know how many I'm going to add?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form_for that creates a new 'Estimate' and each of these estimates can have an unlimited number of 'Items' (this is like a part number, but it will have it's own set of attributes). I would like to be able to create as many instances of the associated Items model as I want to before I submit the form that creates the new Estimate, and then have it create all of the associated Items that go with that Estimate.

I've read a lot in the API on form_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for, I've googled extensively, and I've watched the railscasts about nested model forms, and I've read through my rails 3 book, but I've yet to find a 'rails way' to create all of these new objects in one go from the same form. In the railscast, Ryan has something like this in the controller:

```
def new  
  @estimate = Estimate.new  
  3.times { @estimate.items.build }  
end
```

However, I do not know how many items are going to be on each estimate. I'm also not sure which fields_for syntax I should be using in the view, but I do understand I'll probably have to use JavaScript to dynamically create new form fields.

Here is how my models are related:

```
class Estimate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

and:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :estimates
end
```

So, any ideas? Like I said, I can make my app do this (I'll probably use a lot of AJAX), but I was hoping someone might have a prettier solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the route you are following is the best way to do that. Using JavaScript you can dynamically add as many associated records you want! That isn't pretty enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

??? your way is the best Rails Way.
Perhaps you don't know to build a form for items?
By Rails Guides or Rails API's, you can write following:

```
<%= form_for @estimate do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :xxx %>
    <%= f.text_field :xxx %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |item_field| %>
    <p>
      <%= item_field.label :yyy %>
      <%= item_field.text_field :yyy %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And you can use the sooooo good Gem, 'nested_form'.
see: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Yea, I was just confused because normally you create new instances of the objects and assign them to instance variables in your new action on the controller. However, I don't know how many new objects the user is going to add. Then, once the form is POSTed, I'm not sure how the controller will handle saving the new objects that belong to the just-created parent... I think I might just have jQuery do this all with Ajax when I submit the form that creates the parent, so I can control it better...

Comment: okay, I suggest you a gem, [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form). This is the most simple way to handle new form. This gem has great simple and nice document to build or delete new form.