# Submitting multiple instances of a class using Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, model

I have a bit of an interesting predicament. I have an `:ingredients` field which I'm using to get user-input for an ingredient. Each ingredient belongs to a recipe, which is the `form_for` (the `:ingredients` is the `field_for`). However, the user should be able to enter multiple ingredients, an unlimited amount. Right now I've implemented functionality for adding 1 ingredient, as shown here:

```
<%= form_for(:recipe, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

    <%= fields_for :ingredient do |i| %>
         <%= i.text_field(:quantity, :size => '6', :maxlength => '6') %>
         <%= i.text_field(:units, :size => '20', :maxlength => '20') %> 
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

To simplify things, I'm going to scratch the unlimited requirement, which I will do later with AJAX, and assume the user only puts in a max of 20. I'm confused as to how to design my `form_for` to do that, and to access each of those 20 elements in my controller. Would it be something like `params[:recipe][1...20]`?

I read this question: 
[How can I create multiple instances of an assosiated model from a rails 3 form_for when I don't know how many I'm going to add?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936129/how-can-i-create-multiple-instances-of-an-assosiated-model-from-a-rails-3-form-f)

but I'm still stuck and I would like to avoid using Gems if possible (silly constraint I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `nested_form` gem inorder to add `multiple ingredients`. Also look at

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

inside recipe controller new action..

```
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    @recipe = @recipe.ingredients.build
end
```

inside view

```
<%= nested_form_for(@recipe, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I do have a `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `Recipe` model, but why would I need it for the `Ingredient` model?

Comment: Okay, I did all that, and I'm getting this error: `undefined method reflect_on_association for NilClass:Class` with this code:

`3: <div class="recipe new">
4:   <h2>Add a new recipe</h2>
5: 
6:   <%= nested_form_for(:recipe, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
7:   `

Comment: Sorry it was a problem with something else. My actual error is this `undefined method link_to_remove for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xcf957e8>`. I thought the `link_to_remove` and `link_to_add methods` were built in?

Comment: both methods defined inside nested_form builder. If you are using custom form_builder you need to extend it with nested form builder

Comment: I don't think I am using a custom one?